# Circle Trim Start from the Top

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am creating a circular progress bar and I wanted to find out how can I start the progress bar from the top and not from the right hand side. I want to start the progress bar where the arrow is pointing.

```
 Circle()
                    .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .opacity(0.4)
                    .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                
                Circle()

                    .trim(from: 0, to: percentage)
                    .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                    .foregroundColor(percentageColor)
                    .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                    .overlay {
                        Text(tweetCount)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                    }
```

[image]

**UPDATE: SOLUTION**

Here is my solution that works.

```
ZStack {
            Circle()
                .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .opacity(0.4)
                .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
            
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0, to: percentage)
                .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: 270), axis: (x: 0, y: 0, z: 1))
                .foregroundColor(percentageColor)
                .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                .overlay {
                    Text(tweetCount)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .transaction { transaction in
                            transaction.animation = nil
                        }
                }
                
        }
```

Comment: Take your "solution" and make it "self answered question"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of the solution that worked for me.

```
ZStack {
            Circle()
                .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .opacity(0.4)
                .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
            
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0, to: percentage)
                .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
                .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: 270), axis: (x: 0, y: 0, z: 1))
                .foregroundColor(percentageColor)
                .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                .overlay {
                    Text(tweetCount)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .transaction { transaction in
                            transaction.animation = nil
                        }
                }
                
        }
```

Comment: And also, update this as the accepted answer. Makes it easier for users in the future to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just **rotate** your inner circle to **-45 degrees**

```
ZStack {
        Circle()
            .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
            .opacity(0.4)
            .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
        
        Circle()
            .trim(from: 0, to: percentage)
            .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -45))  // copy and paste this line              .foregroundColor(percentageColor)
            .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
            .overlay {
                Text(tweetCount)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .transaction { transaction in
                        transaction.animation = nil
                    }
            }
            
    }
```